# can't change selection after DDL get deafult value

Tags: asp.net, webforms

am having a data based dropdownlist which the default selection is set by user session. it is working fine, but if i try to select a different item on the list after, its jump back to the default. am using visual studio 2015, web form, asp.net

i try selecting default item in 2 way and still the same problem

```
if (Session["plyer2"] != null) {

        string DropDownListSelected = Session["plyer1"].ToString();
        DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
        DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(DropDownListSelected).Selected = true;
        DropDownList2.SelectedValue = Session["plyer2"].ToString(); }
```

have been searching google for the last 2 day didn't find help

the DDL is autopostback

the code is in the .aspx.cs file: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

the databind is in the .aspx file

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="forshow" DataValueField="forshow" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">בחר גארד</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [forshow] FROM [players] WHERE ([position] = @position)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="גארד" Name="position" QueryStringField="גארד" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Where is this code located (in which method) and where do you databind the dropdownlists?

Comment: the code is in the .aspx.cs file:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

the databind is in the .aspx file

Answer (score 0):

well its no a real answer to the problem, but since I'm using session to select item, i add

```
            Session.Abandon();
```

so its cancelling the IF statement next page load and that's good enough for me